# How to make major upgrades get default target path from previous installation

Tags: installshield

I have made a basic msi project. Then I make a major upgrade package for it. when I run the major upgrade package I found that I must determine the installation path.

Is it possible to let major upgrade package to automatically install into path that user has determined in installation of previous version?

Thanks

Comment: [Remember Pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/).

Answer (score 0):

No, This can't be done automatically. if the Installation directory of previous is stored in your product registry or some config file, you may read it the same using custom action and set the value of INSTALLDIR property.

In case, if you didn't stored the Installation directory of previous version, then it can be read from the following Key (if stored automatically):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{Product_Code_of_Previous_Install}\

Value: InstallLocation

{Product_Code_of_Previous_Install} value can be read from the public property which is being set in Upgrade table under ActionProperty column.